# How to enable jest cache in Azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, jestjs, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

So I'm trying to use jest for a project since it was supposed to be faster than jasmine/karma. This is true only for my local machine, once I try to run jest in the ci is about 2-3 as slow as jasmine/karma.

My main goal here is to reduce the time it takes to perform those unit tests, so I decided to try storing the jest cache using the cache@2 task.

In my jest.config.ts I have this:

```js
import type { Config } from 'jest';

const config: Config = {
  // other configurations...
  cacheDirectory: '<rootDir>/.jest-cache'
};

export default config;
```

then in my build.yml I have the following:

```yaml
  - task: Cache@2
    displayName: 'Check for jest cache'
    inputs:
      key: 'jest | “$(Agent.OS)” | $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/yarn.lock'
      path: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/apps/${{ parameters.AppName }}/.jest-cache'
      cacheHitVar: 'JestCacheRestored'
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'), ne('${{ parameters.UnitTestCommand }}', 'disabled'))
  - script: |
      yarn test --maxWorkers=50%%
    displayName: Unit Tests & set cache
```

*As a note `yarn test` is doing this: `nx run test --configuration development`*

So now, this seems to work. The unit tests ran successfully, and the first time there wasn't a cache hit. The second time, it restores the cache, and then runs the unit tests. The problem is performance hasn't improved whatsoever.

The jest cache seems to be dependent on the node_modules, so I used yarn-lock as the key. I would have expected this to work, but now I'm seeing the tests being even slower. If I run the tests a second time, then they run incredible faster like 2min vs 12min. So I think there is something related to the cache, but I'm unsure as what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I just enabled this for a project very similar to yours.  However our cache directory is a bit simpler than your attempt.

Our jest config:

```
const config = {
   cacheDirectory: '<rootDir>/.jest_cache',
   ...
```

Our cache task:

```
      - task: Cache@2
        inputs:
          key: 'jest | "$(Agent.OS)" | package-lock.json'
          restoreKeys: |
            "jest" | "$(Agent.OS)" | "$(Build.SourceBranch)"
          path: .jest_cache
        env:
          VSO_DEDUP_REDIRECT_TIMEOUT_IN_SEC: 5
        displayName: Cache jest
```

During testing I used a temporary script task to verify the folder contained the cached files I was expecting.
`echo ls .jest_cache -R`

The first execution saw no savings, but subsequent runs are about 2.5x faster.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it ended up being a logical problem. I have multiple projects with the same configuration, and I wanted a key-path pair for each unique project. I had this:

```
key: 'jest | “$(Agent.OS)” | $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/yarn.lock'
path: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/apps/${{ parameters.AppName }}/.jest-cache'
```

where the path is unique through the appName, but I was reusing the key without noticing since all projects share the same yarn.lock. I just needed to add a part of the key that would be unique per app, so I just added the jest.config.ts file like this:

```
key: 'jest | $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/apps/${{ parameters.AppName }}/jest.config.ts | “$(Agent.OS)” | $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/yarn.lock'
path: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/apps/${{ parameters.AppName }}/.jest-cache'
```

Plus this have the added benefit that if the jest configuration changes, the cache won't be used.