# Sharding JestJS tests on Azure DevOps pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, jestjs

I've been using JestJS to scan a codebase, but it's proving to be a little slow. I started to look into this, and found [this blog post](https://jestjs.io/blog/2022/04/25/jest-28#sharding-of-test-run) about being able to 'shard' Jest tests.

A lot of web searching yielded a few articles on how to do this, but they were for GitHub Actions or CircleCI. They mention using a strategy [matrix].

- https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2022/05/13/jest-shard-test-github-actions/
- https://medium.com/@mfreundlich1/speed-up-your-jest-tests-with-shards-776e9f02f637
- https://artsy.github.io/blog/2022/09/07/quick-tips-to-speed-up-ci/

I am using Azure DevOps pipelines and could not get this approach to work.

What I did get to work is having a step template where the Jest CLI binary is run from that takes a shard parameter. I then have to create one job per shard and call the step template passing it the shard.

It does work, but it does not look elegant or efficient to me. As the tests end up across multiple runners/nodes I cannot share between them and have to checkout, build, etc. for every shard job.

Is this really the only way to do this on Azure DevOps? Or have I missed a trick?

`main_pipeline.yaml`

```yaml
# run each jest passing a shard value to split them and process in parallel
      - job: test1
        displayName: 'test shard 1'
        steps:
          - template: ./steps/git-checkout.yaml
          - template: ./steps/node_install.yaml
          - template: ./steps/yarn_install.yaml
          - template: ./steps/jest_tests.yaml
            parameters:
              shard: 1/4

      - job: test2
        displayName: 'test shard 2'
        steps:
          - template: ./steps/git-checkout.yaml
          - template: ./steps/node_install.yaml
          - template: ./steps/yarn_install.yaml
          - template: ./steps/jest_tests.yaml
            parameters:
              shard: 2/4

      - job: test3
        displayName: 'test shard 3'
        steps:
          - template: ./steps/git-checkout.yaml
          - template: ./steps/node_install.yaml
          - template: ./steps/yarn_install.yaml
          - template: ./steps/jest_tests.yaml
            parameters:
              shard: 3/4

      - job: test4
        displayName: 'test shard 4'
        steps:
          - template: ./steps/git-checkout.yaml
          - template: ./steps/node_install.yaml
          - template: ./steps/yarn_install.yaml
          - template: ./steps/jest_tests.yaml
            parameters:
              shard: 4/4
```

`steps/jest_tests.yaml`

```yaml
# Pass the test job shard number as a param from the calling pipeline job
  - script: |
      TARGET=native node_modules/jest-expo/bin/jest.js --maxWorkers=100% --forceExit --shard ${{ parameters.shard }}
    displayName: 'running jest test shard ${{ parameters.shard }}'

  - task: PublishTestResults@2
    displayName: 'publish test results'
    inputs:
      testResultsFiles: '**/junit.xml'
```

Has anyone seen/done this on Azure DevOps in a better way? Or is this as good as it gets for this?

Comment: Have you found out anything about sharding? I'm looking into it myself. I do have two suggestions for you though. First, I'd try using MaxWorkers=50% or even less. It seems counter intuitive, but at 100% jest will span every worker it possible can. They will all fight for resources and slow each other down very significantly. I've found at 50% is usually 2x or so faster. See this question for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71287710/why-does-jest-run-faster-with-maxworkers-50

Comment: My second suggestion is to use @cache2 if you are not currently using it. I had a question about this for azure devops: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76493744/how-to-enable-jest-cache-in-azure-pipelines/77222554#77222554